# Ubuntu 19.10/qemu4.0 Not able to set "kernel_irqchip=on" in libvirt

Tags: virtualization, qemu, 19.10

I have multiple issues with windows 10 guest after upgrading to 19.10. I read that I need to set the kernel_irqchip=on

I did the following in the machine xml file.

```
...
  <qemu:commandline>
    <qemu:arg value='-machine'/>
    <qemu:arg value='accel=kvm'/>
    <qemu:arg value='kernel_irqchip=on' />
  </qemu:commandline>
</domain>
```

I get the following error when I start the machine.

> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 1080, in create
>       if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virDomainCreate() failed', dom=self) libvirt.libvirtError: internal error: process exited while
>   connecting to monitor: 2019-10-31T18:26:36.904432Z qemu-system-x86_64:
>   kernel_irqchip=on: Could not open 'kernel_irqchip=on': No such file or
>   directory

What is the appropriate way of setting that flag on using libvirt (not the qemu command line)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to (in fact you shouldn't) force that in via qemu-commandline (and if you do it is `kernel-irqchip` instead of `kernel_irqchip`).

This is controlled via the `ioapic` feature.
You should use the feature that is like:

```
 <features>
   <ioapic driver='kvm'/>
 </features>
```

Hereby driver `kvm` maps to *"kernel_irqchip=on"* and driver `qemu` maps to *"kernel_irqchip=split"*.

Also could you check if your issue might be the same as [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qemu/+bug/1849720) and if so chime in there. Especially if kernel-irqchip really helps state so

Comment: I would like to add that my freezing issues with windows 10 is only when I use OVMF bios and it temporary resolves if I restart  libvirtd prior to booting the win10 guest. Also the freezing issues seems to be related to an IRQ. After 5 minutes of freezing with high CPU load my system is back to normal.

Comment: I read somewhere that I also need to have this in features <ioapic driver='kvm'/>. This change did not fix my issues.

Comment: I have add the <irqchip mode='on'/>. I get this error: libvirt.libvirtError: unsupported configuration: unexpected feature 'irqchip'. Is this a bug in the implementation of libvirt in 19.10

Comment: Sorry @user63726 , this was based on a [former version](https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2017-April/msg00933.html) but eventually got accepted as [this version](https://libvirt.org/git/?p=libvirt.git;a=commit;h=6b5c6314b2f7a3b54c94a591e6b0dcd13ef1c6ce). you need ioapic modes to define it [like here](https://libvirt.org/git/?p=libvirt.git;a=blob;f=src/qemu/qemu_command.c;h=be9839cc64ef83663e987a6ebcaa9d8c188a2035;hb=HEAD#l7218). Updating my comment above ...